# c# PDF file concatenation

Tags: c#, pdf

Does anyone know of a good way to load PDF files from an external resource and contatenate them together to produce a single PDF document.

Is there some component you can receomend?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73950/combine-pdfs-c

Comment: See the source code of http://live.gnome.org/PdfMod it already does it and more.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566127/asp-net-converting-and-merging-documents-into-single-pdf

Answer (score 2):

I would use PDFSharp: http://pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=52&Itemid=45

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't use C#, but the way I typically do this is to use ghostscript:

gs -q -sPAPERSIZE=letter -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=out.pdf in1.pdf in2.pdf in3.pdf ...

Basically, this prints out several pdfs in sequence, but redirects the output to a output pdf, effectively concatenating them.

Check out this explanation: http://ansuz.sooke.bc.ca/software/pdf-append.php

Comment: Unfortunately I need to do this in C#.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I work at Atalasoft.  Our [DotImage Document Imaging SDK](http://atalasoft.com/products/dotimage) can do this.  Here's a [whitepaper with all of the code you need](http://www.atalasoft.com/products/dotimage/white-papers/building-pdf-documents-with-dotimage).

It's simply:

```
PdfDocument.Combine("FinalReport.pdf", "CoverSheet.pdf";,
                                   "Disclaimer.pdf", "Report.pdf");
```